# Keep configuration out of war in Spring Boot Web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, gradle

According to the Tomcat official documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html, in section Defining a context. There are various ways to define context.

1. Server Level by editing server.xml
2. By putting config in xml format on $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ location.

   3. Putting config within war.

I am trying to follow 2 option with my Spring boot application. But I am not able to accomplish this deployment is getting failed. Is there a specific difference with Spring boot which I am missing?

Comment: If you defined dependencies for spring-boot-web, it will start an embedded webserver by default. You would need to change the buildscript then. Otherwise you probably need to provide more info about the script and the error message you get.

Comment: Here I have not done anything special. I created Spring MVC helloworld app with spring boot using gradle war plugin, and kept the war file out of tomcat on Desktop. Along with this I created one xml file in which I put the below tag <Context 
  docBase="<absolute path to my war file>" 
  reloadable="true" 
/> in file. and tried to deploy this file by putting it at the location specified in option 2.